# Installing MS Office in Ubuntu 15.10 with PlayOnLinux with setup.exe

Tags: wine, 15.10, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I have MS office 2007 without a CD, with setup.exe. When installed using Wine, there are problems with MSXML ([probably just as here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604548/how-to-install-missing-msxml-5-0-dll-in-ubuntu-14-04lts/604592)), so I have tried PlayOnLinux. But it always requires CD and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240191/installing-ms-office-in-ubuntu-without-cd-rom) sadly did not help:

```
playonlinux setup.exe
...
[many lines]
...
nc: port number too small: 0
```

Any ideas?

*Backup solution*: According to your experience, would MS Office 2010 behave better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick workaround:

When asked for the CD-ROM drive, click "other" and then manually enter the path to the directory where your "setup.exe" is located.
Note that you should create a new folder for this because PlayOnLinux will search the whole folder recursively for the file.

This way, the installation script will still do stuff like overriding DLLs and creating shortcuts.

*edit*
One more note:
The install script you are using is made for the CD version. It is possible that the non-CD installer is completely different and needs additional components to be installed.
Please let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's recommanded to use `LibreOffice`, you still can install MS office in Ubuntu with `PlayOnLinux` using a CD or `Wine` using an .exe file which is your case.

Try to follow those guides. [Office 2010](http://nithinaneeshsct06bt.blogspot.fr/2013/02/install-microsoft-office-2010-in-ubuntu.html) , [Office 2007](http://nithinaneeshsct06bt.blogspot.fr/2012/05/install-microsoft-office-2007-in-ubuntu.html) .

Install mesa OpenGL
`sudo apt-get install mesa-utils mesa-utils-extra libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dev`

then create a link to OpenGL 32-bit library `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so` and 
`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so`

Install Wine

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install wine winetricks`

Set Office to the 32 bits version ( 64 bits will not work )

`export WINEPREFIX="/home/$(whoami)/.wine/office2007/"
 export WINEARCH="win32"`

Run `winetricks` and pick `Select the default wineprefix` then `Install a Windows DLL or component` and choose those packages `vcrun2008, dotnet20, dotnet40, msxml6, riched20, riched30, gdiplus, vb3run, vb4run, vb5run, vb6run` close and run `wine Setup.exe`.

Comment: Access2007, Groove2007 and Outlook2007 will not work though , so if you want to use one of them it's better to work on 2010 version

Comment: Hm... "No package wine-gecko1.4"...

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 32bits or 64bits version ?

Comment: Okay .. Answer edited